# Slider not sending information unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, slider, mouse

So I am making an options menu for my FPS game and so far have developed an audio slider, using the same idea I tried making a sensitivity slider for the mouse. It seems to get the information needed and send it to the game object, but after that it doesn't seem to send it to the other script that controls the FPS camera.

```
//this script controls taking information from a slider in the menu
public float mouseSens;

public void SetSens(float mouseSpeed)
{
    mouseSens = mouseSpeed;
}


//this is the fps camera script
public GameObject mouseInfo; //I tried linking to the game object that holds the information
public float mouseSensitivity; //this is the float that controls mouse sensitivity.


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    //I originally put the float mouseSensitivity = mouseInfo code here but it didn't work.

}

private void Awake()
{
    float mouseSensitivity = mouseInfo.GetComponent<SettingsMenu>().mouseSens; //this is my current try to make it work.
}
```

Any help on this would be very much appreciated. And sorry if this post if formatted wrong, this is my first time posting on stack. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, on your FPS camera, you have a script that allows you to control it with the mouse.  Let's imagine that script is called FPSControllerScript (it's probably not, but just replace FPSControllerScript with the actual name of your the script attached to your camera).

In FPSControllerScript you probably have a variable called something like "mouseSensitivity" or "mouseSpeed".  Let's say it's mouseSensitivity.  Add the following method to your FPSControllerScript.

```
public void SetMouseSensitivity(float value) {
    mouseSensitivity = value;
}
```

Then, the script attached to your slider should be:

```
[SerializeField]
private GameObject _FPSCamera;

public void SetSens(float mouseSpeed)
{
    _FPSCamera.GetComponent<FPSControllerScript>().SetMouseSensitivity(mouseSpeed);
}
```

In the unity editor, drag the FPSCamera object into the field for _FPSCamera (it will be an empty field in the script component for the slider when you look at it in the inspector on the right).

Since you have already got a volume control working, I'm assuming you know how to set your SetSens method as the onValueChanged handler for your slider.

You may have to modify the range of your slider or do some additional calculations for mouseSpeed to ensure the values are reasonable.

Comment: Thank you! I tested the code out and it works. The only problem I am running into is that since the game I am making is multiplayer I have to instantiate it and it becomes a clone. I am sure that I can figure this out on my own. Sorry for taking so long to respond and mark as working. Life's been a little hectic! Again thanks a bunch!

Comment: No worries. Best of luck with your game.